# Power Apps- Model Driven App How to select the colors in a Pie Chart

Tags: powerapps, model-driven-development, model-driven-app

I am new to Power Apps Model Driven App, I have started working on a POC and got some feedbacks from my manager:

1. I have used a Pie Chart on a Data verse Table where there they have suggested for some color changes as per the count.
2. In the chart by default it is showing me count of a particular item, rather then count we need to show the percentage, I have tried with some options in the Chart Page but nothing has worked.
3. How to disable the Drill Down Button on the Dashboard.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

To change the colour of the pie chart:

Select the Pie Chart control on the form or view.
In the right-hand pane, you will see the properties of the Pie Chart.
Scroll down to the "Series" property section.
Expand the series you want to modify by clicking on the arrow icon next to it.
Within the series, you will find a property called "Color".

To display the percentage instead of count in the Pie Chart:

Also in the properties section on the right, also in the "Series" section - you will find a property called "Value". By default, it is set to "Count", click on the dropdown next to it and select "Percentage".

How to disable the Drill Down Button on the Dashboard:

In the properties section of the Dashboard, look for a property called "Enable Drill Down" (or something like that). Just set it to No or False and then save the changes.

Its been a while since i worked with PowerApps, hope this helps!

Comment: hey @Locoz, Thanks for the quick reply
I have tried a lot to find all the options that u have mentioned, but i couldn't find any of them, if possible can u provide the screenshot that will be very helpful to fix my issues

Answer (score 0):

Please use Advanced Chart Editor in Xrmtoolbox to modify the chart colors and add percentage to the label.

Advanced Chart Editor:
https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/ITLec.CRMChartGuy.XRMToolBox.AdvancedChartEditor/

Sample below
https://crmtipoftheday.com/1095/add-percentage-labels-to-pie-charts/

To know more on editing Charts visit below:
https://crmchartguy.wordpress.com/

However there is no known way to disable drilldown in model driven app charts. There was some hack to make the attributes non-searchable back in crm 2011 days but not sure if it works or if there is any implications on changing searchable.

https://mayankp.wordpress.com/2012/05/22/crm-2011-chart-drill-down-enabledisable/